# Reverse words in orace based on delimeter

Tags: oracle11g

I have a table like below.

`columnA   columnB
       1      /Hello/Hai/How
       2      /Hi/Hello/Hey`

need to display the above table in below format(reverse the words based on delimiter '/'),

`columnA   columnB
       1      How/Hai/Hello/
       2      Hey/Hello/Hi/`

May I know how to achieve this in Oracle, I am a newbie to Oracle.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Its Hey/Hello/Hi/ for columnB, where columnA=2 right?

Comment: yes, Sorry for the typo,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you should use stored procedure for this kind of business specific logic/needs.  Which gives an added advantage of writing necessary test cases and documentation.  In case if you are looking for one line answers here it goes.. you can tailor that to your need. But if I'm you I'll write a stored procedure which does the job.  If this is needed by your application then I'll read the string as it and do this logic in application code like java/ruby/perl etc.  Hope this helps

```
SELECT SUBSTR('abc,def,ghi', INSTR('abc,def,ghi',',', -1, 1)+1) ||','|| SUBSTR('abc,def,ghi', INSTR('abc,def,ghi',',', 1, 1)+1,INSTR('abc,def,ghi',',',1,2)-INSTR('abc,def,ghi',',',1,1)-1)  ||','||  SUBSTR('abc,def,ghi', 1 ,INSTR('abc,def,ghi', ',', 1, 1)-1) FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: what if column having more than one 3 values or less than 3 values, any generalized way is there?.

Comment: yes, the generic solution would be to have this logic written in application code or use oracle stored procedure.